# Get Updated Token in new "Sign in with Google" (One-Tap Sign-in)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-one-tap, sign-in-with-google

I am implementing Sign-in-with Google in my front end and using the token to validate my API calls in backend.

In Frontend, I implemented Sign in with Google like the following.

```js
 google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "51....796-2b4...........8pv3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: googleSigninCallback,
 })

google.accounts.id.prompt() // Calling the prompt
```

In the above `googleSigninCallback` callback I am getting success response with the following object.

```
{
  clientId: "3243287432...............",
  client_id: "3243287432...............",
  credential: "eyGudgs........dsfgh",
  select_by: "user"
}
```

Using the above received `credential` I am able to validate the user in backend with the following code.

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
const client = new OAuth2Client("51....796-2b4...........8pv3.apps.googleusercontent.com");
const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: "eyGudgs........dsfgh,
    audience: "51....796-2b4...........8pv3.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  });
```

Everything works fine in this flow.

But the problem is the above received `credential` will expire in one hour, So before that how can I get a new Token/ update the token so that the user can be kept logged in without asking for a One-Tap sign-in every time it expires?

I checked the documentation and couldn't find any answer anywhere.
DOC: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview